# Webmatrix - setting variable from querystring as int

Tags: razor, query-string, webmatrix

i am currently looking for a way to set the amount of results i show depending on if a querystring has been set.

So basically, i first want to check to see if a querystring called pagesize is present. If that is set to a value of 10, then i need it to change a variable to 10. If it's not set, then the variable is set to 6.

Here's my current code:

```
var pageSize = 0;

if (Request.QueryString["pagesize"].AsInt = 10)
{
    pageSize = 10;
}
else
{
    pageSize = 6;
}
```

The error i'm getting back is "Cannot assign to 'AsInt' because it is a 'method group'"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, [the `AsInt` method is an extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548141%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Just add some brackets to call the method, also missing an extra `=`, as per the comments:

```
var pageSize = 0;

if (Request.QueryString["pagesize"].AsInt() == 10)
{
    pageSize = 10;
}
else
{
    pageSize = 6;
}
```

You can further simplify your code by taking advantage of the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). The following line achieves the same result:

`var pageSize = Request.QueryString["pagesize"].AsInt() == 10 ? 10 : 6;`

Comment: I tried that earlier, and i get this message: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tried it and it works fine. Can you post your code, or put it in http://pastebin.com/ and add a link? You will see that error if you're trying to assign a value to something that can't have a value assigned to it, usually because it returns a value!

Comment: Sorry - just worked out what you mean! You're also missing an `=`, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, i should have spotted that too! Regardless, it works a treat, thanks for your help. I'll look to utilise the conditional operator too, looks like it could make things a darn sight cleaner!